# Sex with professor as graduate student

Tags: personal-misconduct

What are the do and do nots with regards to sexual relations between a professor and graduate student?

As long as they aren't your advisor or on your committee is it considered OK?

How does this work?

Comment: Dangerous, in many ways, and in any case.

Comment: They’re your colleague. You expose yourself to MANY problems by engaging in conduct this way. Particularly if you come from the U.S, Title 9 can crush you.

Comment: Maybe check your university’s rulebook. Maybe it is explicitly forbidden?

Comment: What are your institutions rules?

Comment: I looked at my university website and it doesn't indicate that's in any violation of university policy so long as nothing is coerced.

Comment: Looking more closely, as long as the professor isn't in a supervisory role it's considered OK.

Comment: [This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/93901/40589) also has a related discussion.

Comment: Is the prof in your department?

Comment: Yes, she works on a joint project but she's not an advisor or related to any of my work directly.

Comment: How can someone working on a joint project not be related to your work?

Comment: There's a global system but her area of expertise is completely separate, it's liking calling the person who designed the seats on a boeing aircraft related to the person who designed the wing.

Comment: Did you meet this person in a work context, or is it complete coincidence? If so, they seem to be closer to your work than you are indicating. Someone who is a professor on a team of professors that includes your advisor and that manages the overall project that you are involved in is not someone unrelated to your work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I’ll address you as the graduate student based on the phrasing of the question, hope I’m not being too presumptuous.

In the US, the professor can’t be your advisor if sexual or romantic relations are taking place. They can’t be on your thesis committee. They can’t be teaching a class you’re taking, can’t be supervising you as a TA, can’t be writing you a letter of recommendation, can’t be in any position of authority over you whatsoever, during the relationship and most probably at any time in the future. If none of those things are an issue and you’re a consenting adult, and barring any specific institutional policy to the contrary, you’re in the clear and are free to behave in any way that any other adult is allowed to.

Keep in mind some people in academia would still feel uncomfortable with the situation and may be critical towards you and/or the professor if they become aware of the relationship. Depending on the details, your and the professor’s professional reputation and career may be at some risk. Sex tends to make people uncomfortable, sometimes for good reasons, sometimes not.

Comment: Some places have much stricter rules than this.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist that wouldn’t be inconsistent with what I wrote. I’d still like to see examples supporting your claim. And note that it would be very problematic (and potentially legally questionable) for a university to arbitrarily restrict its graduate students’ right to date people of their choice, including from the campus community - any restrictions of this type will have to have some rational basis, and with the lack of a supervisory role or other type of authority differential, I don’t quite see what that basis would be, except perhaps at a private religious institution.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate, I do not see a need for further discussion here.  https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/are-relationships-allowed-between-students-and-faculty

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist thanks for the link. Yes, I think there are other existing questions discussing related things. And yet the post you linked does not support your claim about places with “much stricter rules”. I imagine readers here will accordingly treat your claim with a measure of skepticism.

Comment: @DanRominick "the post you linked does not support your claim" False.  Let's not discuss further.